# how to stop the process take table offline in sql server managment studio

Tags: sql-server

i am at work and accidentally i click on take offline to the database and i want to stop this process, what can i do?

Comment: Did you shut the whole instance down? In sql server config manager you can restart the instances.

Comment: shut down sql server process or may be whole server if it doesn't affect any users

Comment: i am thinking on kill the take ofline process, this affect the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution was this:

check the process running with

```
EXEC sp_who2
```

search for the one that was an alter table in my case the 78, i get info about the spid command with:

```
DBCC INPUTBUFFER(78)
```

once i was sure that was the process i kill it with:

```
KILL 78
```

Answer (score 1):

If you did this via SSMS, just shut down SSMS - that'll kill the process you started by the "take offline".

Then, next time, check this:

select db_name(dbid) , * from sys.sysprocesses where db_name(dbid) like 'theNameOfTheDbYouWantToTakeOffline'

....and verify these processes can be safely stopped....stop them, and go for it.

Alternatively, you can also check the "Drop All Active Connections" checkbox in the Take Database Offline dialog box....